# Bash script to run command on all files in folder fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to run this command on all .wa files within this folder (ideally with subfolders):
./runtest Basic prog -t abc.wa

The script I wrote returns an error:

```
for filename in ./examples/*.wa;
do
    ./runtest Basic prog -t "${filename}"
done
```

When running this with ./testscript I get:
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Can the script also add to the console output the name of the current file?

Comment: Does your script has DOS line endings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should make it:

```
find ./examples -type f -name '*.wa' -exec ./runtest Basic prog -t "{}" \; -print
```

`find` is your friend. Have a look at its man page, it is worth reading.

Comment: This works but isn't materially different here *and* may be **much** more costly depending on what else is in the `examples` directory.

Comment: What do you mean by more costly? As the initial for-do-done loop spawns a new shell for each file and as Pete asked for _ideally with subfolders_ I guess the `find` way should be rather efficient.

Comment: The original doesn't spawn sub-shells at all. It does run `runtest` but you can't avoid that. I'd missed `ideally with subfolders` which makes `find` actually useful here. My apologies for that. And the costly was if subfolders weren't desired for the search and they did exist (and were large) then `find` would search them and the glob wouldn't.

Comment: Sorry to insist, it **does** spawn a shell **because** it runs `runtest`. So, on a pure efficiency point of view, using `find` is at least equivalent. And the good point is that it descends in the sub-directories.

Comment: Of course it runs `runtest`. So does yours. That's a requirement. But it doesn't spawn a sub-shell to do that. It just executes it directly. Why do you think there's a sub-shell involved? At what point?

Comment: Give it try: create a `foo.sh` shell script with just `echo $$`. Then, run it in a `for (( i = 1; i < 9; i += 1 )); do ./foo.sh; done` and look at the process ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89189/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the semicolon unless the `do` is on the same line.

Comment: That is **not** a problem in bash. In fact, no in any shell. The semicolon is not required, but is allowed. And perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

To run in all subfolders, use `**` as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

( shopt -s globstar
for filename in ./examples/**.wa
do
    echo "${filename}"
done
)
```